# Samba connection time out on big files with Nautilus

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

**Story:**

I have an external HDD hooked up to my router. I use Nautilus to connect via `smb` to it and when I copy multiple large files (usually above 200MB/file) the speed drops constantly and it comes to a stop for some seconds.

This behaviour is expected since it also happens on my windows PC and android phone, the router takes some seconds to catch his breath or whatever but then the process continues. The problem is that on Ubuntu after a few seconds of write speed at almost 0, I get "connection timed out".

Based on that, I am thinking of disabling the connection timed out feature since I believe it's triggered by those waiting seconds. I assume there should be some kind of config file, but I have no idea where it is and what the command will look like

**TLDR question:**

I want to disable the `smb` connection timed out feature (I assume it's triggered by write speed coming to a stop for some seconds) and force the `smb` to continue the process of copying my large files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**

Using `cp` inside the `terminal` works flawlessly, so this proves that it's a  Nautilus 'feature'